# React Native: Maximum depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm try to update userProfile image but getting that error

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

here is my code

```
class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    userImage: require("../assets/cena.jpg"),
    userName: "John Cena",
    userInfo: "The champ is here",
    modal: false,
    image: null,
    hasCameraPermission: null,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === "granted" });
  }

  pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
      this.props.formikProps.setFieldValue("image", result.uri);
    }
  };

  closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({ modal: false });
  };

  render() {
    
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.7}
            onPress={this.pickImage}
            style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle}
          >
            <MaterialCommunityIcons
              name="camera"
              size={30}
              color={colors.white}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {!this.state.image && (
            <Image style={styles.image} source={this.state.userImage} />
          )}
          {this.state.image && (
            <Image
              style={styles.edit}
              source={this.setState({ userImage: this.state.image })}
            />
          )}
```

can someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

remmove the setState as it should be anonymous otherwise will call on every render

```
 {this.state.image && (
            <Image
              style={styles.edit}
              source={this.setState({ userImage: this.state.image })}
            />
          )}
```

should be

```
 {this.state.image && (
            <Image
              style={styles.edit}
              source={this.state.image}
            />
          )}
```

by the way you can't setState in the source prop as it only be given the picture path !

Comment: so how can I correct it I'm familiar with function base but never done this in class base, can you help?

Comment: `Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.` got that error and that warning `promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.formikProps.setFieldValue`

Comment: comment that ```formik``` line.

Comment: i removed it but it's not setting userImage to image i choose from gallery bcoz i need to use setState, it's so easly in function base

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this :

```
    {this.state.image ? (
            <Image style={styles.image} source={this.state.userImage} />
          ) :  (
            <Image
              style={styles.edit}
              source={this.state.userImage}
            />
          )}
```

You can also use the onError prop of image component to change the source prop.

Comment: `Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.formikProps.setFieldValue')` where should i use setstate?

Comment: What is the purpose of changing state?

Comment: The error is in your formik line, comment it out and try to run the code.

Comment: i removed it but it's not setting userImage to image i choose from gallery bcoz  i need to use setState, it's so easly in function base